# Xen booting stuck on 'Loading initial ramdisk...'

Tags: centos, virtualization, grub, xen

After successfull instalation of xen, The xen kernel cannot booting and stuck on `Loading inital ramdisk`

I followed the instalation tutorial from [here](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen4CentOS).

I'm using `centos-release-7-2.1511.el7.centos.2.10.x86_64`

This is xen menuentry on my grub.cfg

`menuentry 'CentOS Linux, with Xen hypervisor' --class centos --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-simple-9cfb09c2-7a47-4d52-9e97-e45ea7c8b544' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3 --hint='hd0,msdos3'  9cfb09c2-7a47-4d52-9e97-e45ea7c8b544
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9cfb09c2-7a47-4d52-9e97-e45ea7c8b544
    fi
    echo    'Loading Xen 4.6.1-13.el7 ...'
        if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
            xen_rm_opts=
        else
            xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
        fi
    multiboot   /boot/xen-4.6.1-13.el7.gz placeholder  dom0_mem=1024M,max:1024M cpuinfo com1=115200,8n1 console=com1,tty loglvl=all guest_loglvl=all ${xen_rm_opts}
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.18.34-20.el7.x86_64 ...'
    module  /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.34-20.el7.x86_64 placeholder root=UUID=9cfb09c2-7a47-4d52-9e97-e45ea7c8b544 ro vconsole.keymap=us crashkernel=auto  vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb quiet console=hvc0 earlyprintk=xen nomodeset
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    module  --nounzip   /boot/initramfs-3.18.34-20.el7.x86_64.img
}`

Any idea of what i miss and how can i fix this?